# Itext Curved with fabric js

Tags: javascript, text, fabricjs

How to apply curved text effect with IText in fabric js. User can change curved direction, radius and other parameters. Please help.

```
var text = new fabric.IText(e);

text.CurvedText = fabric.util.createClass(text.Text, text.Collection, {
                        type: "curvedText",
                        radius: 50,
                        range: 5,
                        smallFont: 10,
                        largeFont: 30,
                        effect: "curved",
                        spacing: 20,
                        reverse: !1,
                       /* stateProperties: e,
                        delegatedProperties: g,
                        _dimensionAffectingProps: f,
                        _isRendering: 0,*/
                    });
      canvas.add(text);
      canvas.renderall();
```

do we need any other calculation for curved text.

Comment: Show some code excerpt, what and  you're doing it with your own efforts @Snehalk

Comment: I removed the iText® tag. iText is a PDF library (see [about iText](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/itext/info)), and it seems that this question is about something that is totally unrelated to iText.

Comment: @ Laxmikant Gurnalkar I update question with code i am doing. Also I have tried https://github.com/Skritz/fabric.curvedText but its not working for me.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie correct, the question is about IText, not about iText.